# Considering all the blank values as variable "NA" without hard coding

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data set which has null values in between, I wish to know on a general note, I want to treat these null values as a common character value without assigning or hard coding any value in the data, such that the null too is considered a variable. E.g: Say there are two vectors:

```
a1 <- c("a1","a2","","a3")
a2 <- c("b1","b2","b3","b4")
a12 <- data.frame(a1,a2)
```

Basically, I have a much larger data, considering all blank values as "na" without assigning any value to the blank fields.

Comment: Could you please tell us what you want to do with the data frame

Comment: As a sidenote on the names of empty elements: be careful that a `NULL` value is different from an empty string `''`: `identical(c('a','b',NULL),c('a','b')) # --> TRUE` so a NULL value really is nothing, not like an empty string  `''` or a missing value `NA`.

Comment: @BertilBaron, see I have two columns with a1 and a2, the issue is that "a1" has na values. when I plot a bar chart, "na" introduces an error in the chart, however hard coding the "na" values with variable "na" does the job, I want to use the blank values as a common variable say "na" at the back end and not modify the dataset.

Comment: @BertilBaron, Hi I kind of solved this issue, I am basically looking to create traces in eventlog datasets where null values create issue. Please help me with this post as I am struggling to find a fix, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951307/selection-of-activity-trace-in-a-chart-and-display-in-a-data-table-in-r-shiny

Comment: If any of the solutions provided here, please select one post to accept it as the answer. See this post to learn how to do it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @www, I got it answered from someone. Thanks a lot, however I appreciate your effort for helping me with this post, kindly check my requirement and suggest, Thank a lot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976994/arranging-bars-of-a-bar-plot-with-null-in-descending-order-in-r/47979583#47979583

Comment: @RobertJ On StackOverflow, it is a general practice to accept an answer when people answered your question with valid solutions. This will show future viewers this question has been solved. If you don't do that, I don't see why people want to answer your question.

Comment: @www, sure I'll do that, I appreciate the community's effort in helping me with  the requirement. Also, kindly help me with that post, that null issue has made me struggle for ages now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R base does the job. Try `a12[a12 == ""] <- NA`

```
a12
#    a1 a2
#1   a1 b1
#2   a2 b2
#3 <NA> b3
#4   a3 b4
```

Comment: thanks for replying, See can you help me here, I don't wish to assign NA in the data and modify it, just consider a blank value as a common variable in the backend. the end user should see a blank value only.

Comment: If I got you right, you don't need to set blank values as `NA`, no? What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: If this is just about printing, you could create a `class` and an associated `print` method

Comment: I want to know that is there a way, I can consider these blank values to be "NA" without actually hard coding them.

Comment: That's what `a12[a12 == ""] <- NA` does. The `NA` you see in R is just a missing value indicator - which is different than a blank cell. Check the result of this test `is.na("") == is.na(NA)`. Export your data to an Excel file by using `xlsx::write.xlsx(a12, "a12.xlsx", showNA = FALSE)` and you can see that `NA` are represented as blank cells in Excel.

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I'll check into this, however I kind of figured the solution myself, if I use stringasfactors = F, i don't have to declare the hard code value and I can get the job done, thanks everyone for the support.

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I require your assistance with this another post in which I need help to tweak the logic a little, kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951307/selection-of-activity-trace-in-a-chart-and-display-in-a-data-table-in-r-shiny

Comment: @ANG, kindly help me here with this post.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use `is.na<-` together with a (logical) index vector.

```
is.na(a12) <- a12 == ""
a12
#    a1 a2
#1   a1 b1
#2   a2 b2
#3 <NA> b3
#4   a3 b4
```

Note that a numeric index vector, `which(a12 == "")` would also do the job.

Comment: I figured this out, thanks a lot for your help,kindly help me with this script, I have some issue with displaying table details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951307/selection-of-activity-trace-in-a-chart-and-display-in-a-data-table-in-r-shiny?noredirect=1#comment82886535_47951307

Answer (score 0):

dplyr solution:

Temporarily assign empty strings the NA value inside a pipe:

```
a12%>% mutate_all(. %>% ifelse(. == '',NA,.)) %>% ....
```

(or the same, a bit longer but more conventional syntax:

```
a12%>% mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(x == '', NA, x)) %>% ....
```

After this, coupled by further `%>% ...` you might do something with your data

Comment: kindly help me with this post, I am not sure how to handle null values here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976994/arranging-bars-of-a-bar-plot-with-null-in-descending-order-in-r?noredirect=1#comment82923110_47976994